# Problem setting up jdtls in LunarVim on Windows 10

Tags: lunarvim

I am getting the following error in `:LspLog` :

`[ERROR][2023-06-01 17:43:57] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734 "rpc" "C:\\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\nvim-data\mason\bin\jdtls.CMD" "stderr" 'The command "python" is either misspelled or could not be found.\r\n'`

I already changed the alias for python via `doskey python=py` but...no luck up to now.

Any suggestions what I can do?

P.S. I am using Windows 10

I have already tried as described above but I am out of solutions